# Tridimensional array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have this code:

```
require 'chunky_png'

time1 = Time.now
image = ChunkyPNG::Image::from_file("logo10.png")
height = image.height
width = image.width
nouvelle = Array.new

height.times do |x|
  nouvelle[x] = Array.new
  width.times do |y|
    nouvelle[x][y] = Array.new
    nouvelle[x][y][0] = ChunkyPNG::Color.b(image[x,y])
    nouvelle[x][y][1] = ChunkyPNG::Color.g(image[x,y])
    nouvelle[x][y][2] = ChunkyPNG::Color.r(image[x,y])
  end
end 

time2 = Time.now
puts "temps = " + ((time2 - time1)*1000).to_s + " ms"
```

I have this problem:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
        nouvelle[x][y] = Array.new
                        ^
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
        nouvelle[x][y][2] = ChunkyPNG::Color.r(image[x,y])
                           ^
```

I don't see where the problem is. Can you help me?

Comment: are you sure the problem is here?

Comment: yes because it's all the code

Comment: Please make an edit to say the problem was identified. I considered your question for several minutes before seeing your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can figure this sort of problem out:

```
# encoding: UTF-8

str = '] = A'
str.chars.map(&:ord).join(', ')
# => "93, 160, 61, 32, 65"
```

Notice the second value is 160, which is located at the second character. 160 decimal is 0xA0 hex or a NBSP in Unicode.

Then I typed in the string:

```
str = '] = A'
str.chars.map(&:ord).join(', ')
# => "93, 32, 61, 32, 65"
```

Again, notice the second character is now 32, which is AKA 0x20, AKA "SPACE".

Answer (score 0):

http://repl.it/8Tl

In fact, is a red point who is arrived in my code like you can look with this link.

nouvelle[x][y] = --> there is a character unknow between the ] and the equal